# Adding a string variable in a list everytime the class is provided by information

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment5
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student : Person
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public static int countS = 0;
        public static List<string> studentlist = new List<string>();
        public Student()
        {
            studentlist.Add(Name);
            countS++;

        }
        public static int GetActiveInstances()
        {
            return countS;
        }

    }



    class MainProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Instantiate three Student objects.
            Student Student1 = new Student();
            Student Student2 = new Student();
            Student Student3 = new Student();

            Student1.Name = "John";
            Student2.Name = "Joe";
            Student3.Name = "Jacob";

            for (int i = 0; i < Student.studentlist.Count; i++) // Loop with for.
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Student.studentlist[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Hi guys. What I have in mind is that I want to automatically store every student being initiated in an array/list that I created and eventually, I want to output these students in the console.
Can anyone enlighten me what I did wrong on my program?
Supposedly it will output the 3 names I declare. What I have on the output for the posted program are all blank.

**Next Related Question **

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment6
{

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public virtual void GetInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", Address);
        }
    }


    public class Student : Person
    {
        public void SetStudentInfo(string name, string address)
        {
            Name = name;
            Address = address;
        }

    }

    public class Course //class represents university course
    {
        private ArrayList studentList = new ArrayList();

        public ArrayList StudentList
        {
            get { return studentList; }
            set { studentList = value; }
        }
        //how can I implement this such that I can have the StudentList be updated and printed
        // out to the console from the main 
        public void ListStudents()
        {

            foreach (Student i in StudentList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
    class MainProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var Student1 = new Student { Name = "John" };
            var Student2 = new Student { Name = "Joe" };
            var Student3 = new Student { Name = "Jacob" };

            Course course1 = new Course();

            course1.StudentList.Add(Student1);
            course1.StudentList.Add(Student2);
            course1.StudentList.Add(Student3);

            course1.ListStudents();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code and I want to output every student in my arraylist, the foreach loop should be on the course class. Still, the code is connected on my question so I just ask it here. Can anyone help me revise it? thanks

Comment: Well for one thing, you're not storing any students in the list, it looks like you're storing address, which is null in the default constructor.

Comment: sorry I forgot to edit. But if you will change it to Name, the same result will appear. Try it

Comment: But in your constructor you are still adding a field to the list that hasn't been set yet (was `Address`, now it's `Name`). I added an answer below that adds a reference to the class instance to the list instead, so you can get these properties after they've been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a property that hasn't been set yet (which is what you're currently doing in the default constructor - you're adding the `Name` property before it's been set), you can add a reference to the class instance using the `this` keyword, so the properties of the items in your list (like `Name` or `Address`) get updated when they are set on the class instance.

Also, you don't need a separate variable to keep track of the number of students, since you can just use the `Count` property of the list.

Here's a way you can do this:

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public static List<Student> AllStudents = new List<Student>();

    public Student()
    {
        AllStudents.Add(this);
    }

    public static int GetActiveInstances()
    {
        return AllStudents.Count;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var student1 = new Student {Name = "John"};
    var student2 = new Student {Name = "Joe"};
    var student3 = new Student {Name = "Jacob"};

    foreach (var student in Student.AllStudents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
    }
}
```

Output:

> John
> Joe
> Jacob

**UPDATE**

One way you can protect your internal list, yet still let others query it, would be to make the list `private`, and then expose a public property that returns a *copy* of the list, which prevents people from affecting your private instance if they call `.Add()` or `.Remove()` on it, or try to set it to a new `List<Student>`.

Here's an example:

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    // This is the "official" list. It's private so cannot be changed externally
    private static readonly List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();

    // This property returns a COPY of our private list
    public static List<Student> AllStudents
    {
        get
        {
            var copyOfList = new List<Student>();
            copyOfList.AddRange(StudentList);
            return copyOfList;
        }
    }

    public Student()
    {
        // Add the student to our private list
        StudentList.Add(this);
    }

    public static int StudentCount()
    {
        // Return the count from our private list
        return StudentList.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I'm not recommending this practice. By making the `AllStudents` list public, people can create a new student (which will automatically get added to the list) and then add that student to the list manually by calling `Student.AllStudents.Add(someStudent);` (as many times as they want). They can also remove items from the list. There are ways to prevent this, but hopefully this answers your direct question.

Comment: yeah, this is what I am really looking for. HEHE. Thanks. Can you also post what's your recommendation to not use the public encap?

Comment: May I see what you can recommend for a better implementation?

Comment: I would make the list private and then expose only the methods you want.

Comment: @jbat21 I added a sample of how the class could be modified to protect your internal list but still provide the enumeration functionality. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi sir, Can I ask again? I only did edit my question, I add my next question there. Can you take a look at it and help me solve it? thanks

Comment: That's not how this site works - one question and one answer is the way this site helps the community. But the answer is to write `i.Name` in the loop, or override the `ToString()` method on the `Student` class so it outputs what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question til the next question I post. :)

Answer (score 2):

What I do not get is these line:

```
public static int countS = 0;
public static List<string> studentlist = new List<string>();
public Student()
{
    studentlist.Add(Address);
    countS++;
}
```

What I would suggest is to move these out so that the class is something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And that main is something like this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate three Student objects.
        Student Student1 = new Student();
        Student Student2 = new Student();
        Student Student3 = new Student();

        Student1.Name = "John";
        Student2.Name = "Joe";
        Student3.Name = "Jacob";
        var studentlist = new List<Student>{Student1,Student2,Student3};

        foreach (var student in studentlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. But I already did that. What I want is that it automatically store my initiated students such that I don't have to add something like Student4 and so in var studentlist = new List<Student>{Student1,Student2,Student3};, the program would know that it should add those like what happen in the countS++, it automatically increments whenever new student is inititated